# Is it possible to pass custom parameters to light.exe from a .wixproj?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I've recently upgraded one of my projects to build with Visual Studio 2015.  I build the installer for my project using Wix and I ship the Microsoft CRT merge modules with my project.  There's a known issue where light.exe can issue warnings about some of the GUIDs used in the Merge Modules shipped by Microsoft:

```
light.exe : warning LGHT1076: ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: File, Column:
File, Key(s): api_ms_win_crt_filesystem_l1_1_0.dll.71E1EC1A_562B_3AD1_94CD_84420ED4073F [v:\VS2015\DataNow\Installer\To
olsInstaller\Toolbox.wixproj]
```

I've read that this can be a known problem with these merge modules (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html) and that the warning is benign.  However, I'd like to suppress the warnings by passing:

```
-sw 1076
```

to light.exe but I can't figure out how to pass custom parameters to light.exe using the .wixproj visual studio Wix files.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahaha,

I've finally found the solution.  I don't need to pass parameters to light.exe because there's a section in the .wixproj that can be used to suppress these warnings:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">
    <SuppressAllWarnings>False</SuppressAllWarnings>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)Publish\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <LinkerAdditionalOptions>"$(WixToolPath)difxapp_$(Platform).wixlib"</LinkerAdditionalOptions>
    <SuppressSpecificWarnings>1055;1056;1076</SuppressSpecificWarnings>
    <SuppressIces>ICE80;ICE82</SuppressIces>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: These settings should be available in visual studio project properties -> Tool Settings. Suppress ICE validationas and additional Compiler/Linker parameters if you don't want to edit the proj file itself.